# ListView Horizontal Fling Gesture

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that displays entries for a given date. There are buttons above the listview that allow you to increase/decrease the date. Everything works. What I'm looking to do is replace those buttons and have the user swipe right/left to increase/decrease the date.

What's the best way to go about this? I don't care what item is swiped, often there will be no items in the listview for a given date, just as long as it happens on the listview area. I do have click and longclick listeners on the items already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just implement the OnGestureListener.

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnGestureListener
```

Use a GestureDetector

```
GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(this, this);
```

Pass the touch event of the list to the GestureDetector

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(e);
        return false;
    }
});
```

And finally use the fling method to detect a gesture. You can use the velocity values to detect the direction of the movement.

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there a standard number that represents a fling? I'm using if (velocityX > 150) ... right to left fling. It works but is a bit subjective.

Comment: I used 200 but that is also a guessed value.

Comment: velocityX - The velocity of this fling measured in pixels per second along the x axis.

Comment: Problem is that vertical list scrolling lags: it takes time to see if the touch event is an horizontal fling...