# Horizontal fling with list view: lag problems

Tags: android

I implemented my gesture listener according to this topic: [ListView Horizontal Fling Gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481814/listview-horizontal-fling-gesture)

however, I can see that list scrolling is slower, sometimes (when you scroll very slowly) it blocks too.
I think the problem is in the listener: it takes time to compute values and so get the actual "left to right" fling I'm searching for...isn't there a more efficient way?

**edit**

Problem is here:

```
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
            return false;
        }

        // right to left swipe
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            System.out.println("right to left");
            animatedStartActivity(0);

            // right to left swipe
        }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            System.out.println("left to right");
            animatedStartActivity(1);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

evaluation of this method takes time

**edit2:**
I guess problem is because listview already has its own gesture listener and attaching mine overrides it. It is a problem because listview gesture listener takes in account speed and acceleration too, to give a nice moving effect. My listener is pretty raw, so list scrolling is not smooth anymore..
Even if my onFLing method always returns false (so it does not consume the event) list scrolling is affected...

**edit3:
Ok maybe I found the solution but I need your help!
I can set the onTouchListener on the container layout, problem is that listview actually overrides parent's onTouch so I need to reverse the situation: onTouchEvent on listview has to be intercepted by the parent, so that returning false it is brougth to listview**

Comment: Post some of your code, maybe there are inefficiencies in how your list items are recycling when scrolling.

Comment: No man, I updated the main topic and problem is definely in gesture detector as if I remove it everything goes fine

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!
Problem was that ListView's onTouchEvent performed some other operations! So I extended ListView:

```
public class FlingListView extends ListView{

private GestureDetector detector; //this is my detector

public void setDetector(GestureDetector detector){
    this.detector = detector;
}

public FlingListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public FlingListView(Context context,AttributeSet set) {
    super(context,set);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public FlingListView(Context context,AttributeSet set, int a) {
    super(context,set,a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

     //here I do the magic
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onTouchEvent(ev); //I always do the list on touch event
    return(detector.onTouchEvent(ev)); //..but I return the detector!

}
 }
```

I don't know if this is the best solution but still...it works!